# How to access js array defined in another js file

Tags: javascript, arrays

How do I access a JavaScript array that is defined in another JavaScript file?

Comment: show some code on what you are trying to achieve. Malvolio's answer is correct

Answer (score 14):

If the variable is global, and you include the JS file with the variable first in your HTML file, then it is accessible via the second JS file:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="somefile_with_variable.js"/>
<script type="text/javascript" src="somefile_reading_variable.js"/>
```

Answer (score 5):

Inside a browser, all the .js files share the same global space.  Just refer to it by name.

Answer (score 3):

Include both files on a certain page and you can access the array normally by its name.

Answer (score 2):

In order for this to work define your array as "var" (global variable). 
Go to the JS file where the array is and export it.

```
var globalArray;

export{globalArray, otherFunctionsYouExport};
```

Now go to the JS file you want the access to the array and import the global array. If you have multiple functions to import, use * and it will export everything between the brackets above.

```
import * as chooseName from './path of your JS file you export from';

// to use it write this
chooseName.globalArray // put here the rest of your code
```