# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, arrays, local-storage

I am making a barcode scanning app using phonegap-1.4.1 for android. I need to define a n array `code[]` which can store all the barcode text scanned and i need to define a variable `k` which act as a counter which get incremented by 1 after every scan so that I can store detail in `code[k]`. So here is my previous javascript file where i have defined an array and an variable counter.

```
     localStorage["counter"]=0;
     var code = new Array(100);
     localStorage.setItem("code", JSON.stringify(code));
```

and here is my another js file where i am calling the stored array and printing the value stored in that array as `"id"`. `myvalue1` is the barcode text obtained from the scan.

```
   var barcodeVal = localStorage.getItem("myvalue1");
   var test2 = localStorage.getItem("code");
   code = JSON.parse(test2);
   var k = parseInt(localStorage.getItem("counter"));
   code[k] = "code[k]";
   document.getElementById(code[k]).innerHTML = barcodeVal;
   k = k + 1;
   localStorage["counter"]=k;
   localStorage.setItem("code", JSON.stringify(code));
```

I am calling the barcode scan function again and again. Thats why I am using an array for storing the data of the Barcode scanned.Here is my scan js file as well which gives the value of `myvalue1`

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
  var scanCode = function () {
      window.plugins.barcodeScanner.scan(
          function (result) {

               alert("Scanned Code: " + result.text + ". Format: " + result.format + ". Cancelled: " + result.cancelled);
              localStorage.setItem("myvalue1", result.text);
              window.location.href = 'page5.html';

          }, function (error) {
              alert("Scan failed: " + error);
       });
  }
```

I am getting the error as `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null`. I am new to phonegap and coding . Anyone please help me out with the issue. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to keep track of variable `k`.
You simple manage your all barcode values using below script.

Please check below jsFiddle...Run it twice you can see difference.

### [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kVR74/1/)

```
<script>
function SaveDataToLocalStorage(barcodeValue)
{

    var oldItems = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('barcodes')) || [];
    var newItem = {
        'barcode': barcodeValue
    };
    oldItems.push(newItem);
    localStorage.setItem('barcodes', JSON.stringify(oldItems));

}
SaveDataToLocalStorage("123456879FFGG");
</script>
```

Comment: But for like i will be having like 15-20 barcodes scanned. so wont i be  using an array to store that?

Comment: I thought as i was having the error of innerHTML so i replaced it with jQuery one like `$("#code[k]").text(barcodeVal);`   and this can store the id in it and i will give html direct acess like `id = code[0] ` and likewise. But it didnt work. Is this kind of code possible?

Comment: if you want to use localstorage then my answer helpful to you.

Comment: You can store n number of barcodes. you can check jsfiddle

Comment: If you want to display, just read oldItems in code array and display in table simply.

Comment: You dont need to remember any thing if you use above function

Comment: okay i think this code will work. So all i need to do is get the value out of `barcodes[]` which u have defined here by ` id= barcodes[0]` and so on. Is my approach correct? sorry for bothering you but i am new to coding so its takes time to understand.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/56398/discussion-between-butani-vijay-and-raunak).

Comment: the number you gave me is incorrect. can you give me a valid one?

Comment: Can you look at this question? This is the issue I am facing. 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24486207/barcodescanner2-typeerror-cannot-set-property-innerhtml-of-null

Comment: It should be better if you will send whole your code to me...so i can find problem and give you solution.

Comment: To save and display you just need to do this

Comment: yeah but their has to be a reason why my code is not working its working in jsfiddle but not in eclipse.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24486207/barcodescanner2-typeerror-cannot-set-property-innerhtml-of-null/24486349?noredirect=1#comment37903643_24486349

Comment: I am using is to store values in the array like test2[0] , test2[1],test2[2] and so on

Comment: what is use of this array test2??

Comment: At first i am defining an array code in the local storage then i am calling that array as `test2[]` after that i am storing id of particular value of scan in `test2[k]` for `k=0` then after that i am calling that function again with `k++` , `k=1` and value of next scan being stored in `test2[1]`