# How to access array from another .js file?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I want to get a (Very large) array from another file so it doesn't take up space in my main js file but I cannot figure it out, I have spent about 2 - 3 days searching online but cannot find an answer that will work. I've tried answers from [How to access js array defined in another js file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5242050/how-to-access-js-array-defined-in-another-js-file) aswell as many other sites but nothing is working.

```
// the js file with the array I want
wordList = [
    "this",
    "is",
    "an",
    "array"
]
```

```
// main js file
const word = wordList[Math.floor(Math.random() * wordList.length)];
```

Any help is appreciated :)
EDIT: This is for a browser game if that helps

Comment: Are you using modular javascript?

Comment: I'm not familiar with what that means so I'll assume no

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should add both the scripts to html. Then, you should make the array global:

```js
window.wordList = [
    "this",
    "is",
    "an",
    "array"
]
```

Then in the `main.js` file, you can access the array like this:

```js
const word = window.wordList[Math.floor(Math.random() * wordList.length)];
```

But make sure, you add the script with the array before the main.js file in the html

Answer (score 2):

You can export the variable from first file using export.

```js
// example.js
const WordList = [
    "this",
    "is",
    "an",
    "array"
]

export { WordList };
```

Then, import the variable in main.js file using import.

```js
import { WordList } from './example.js'
```

Comment: I've tried this and I receive the following errors:

"Cannot use import statement outside a module" 
and
"Unexpected Token 'import'"
Might be worth mentioning I'm trying this in a browser

Comment: Try adding  type="module" to your script tag

Comment: I've tried this and I receive some new errors: 

"Access to script at 'file_path" from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, https, ipns, chrome-untrusted, ipfs, data, chrome, chrome-extension." and "GET 'file_path' net::ERR_FAILED    (along with the original "Cannot use import statement outside a module")

Comment: If you try to open a web-page locally, via file:// protocol, you’ll find that import/export directives don’t work. Use a local web-server, such as static-server or use the “live server” capability of your editor, such as VS Code Live Server Extension to test modules.

Comment: This has helped but there is one more error, "Cannot use import statement outside a module". Sorry if it's an obvious answer this is out of my depth and I'm new to all this multi-file stuff

Comment: Not sure how your code looks, but maybe you forgot type="module" to that script tag as well?

Comment: It's alright another comment worked, I guess I was doing something wrong with this solution. Thanks for the help though :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to export your array and import it in any file you want. Full details of the export/import mechanism can be found in the next [Stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/950087/how-do-i-include-a-javascript-file-in-another-javascript-file/950146#950146)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).